# In R, how to fread through ssh and awk

Tags: r, string, ssh, data.table

There are a lot of files on a remote server, that I would like to `fread` into R.
If I am on remote in R, I can do

```
require(data.table)
f <- fread(cmd="awk '{print $0\"\t\"FILENAME}' path/to/myfile*.txt")
```

and I get the expected output, with filenames as additional column.

If I am on local and need to go through ssh, I tried:

```
f <- fread(cmd='ssh user@remote awk \\"{print $0 FILENAME}\\" path/to/myfile*.txt')
```

but I only get the filenames in `f`, no content though. I guess I'm not getting the `cmd=` string to properly go through ssh, am I escaping something incorrectly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `ssh ... > data.csv` and then `Rscript -e 'data.table::fread("data.csv")'` did it worked?

Comment: I can ssh into remote and run awk and Rscript separately, yes. But not all within R from local. I guess `ssh remote 'awk ...'  > data.csv` would work but thats not really what I need. Maybe I could combine with `system()` but that seems a little cumbersome. I will keep that in mind

Comment: This writing to data.csv I meant to write to file on local machine, so something like `bash -c 'ssh ...' > data.csv`

Answer (score 0):

The content is missing because the actual command that have been executed in the remote server is `awk "{print sh FILENAME}" path/to/myfile*.txt`, since the `$0` has been substituted to `"sh"` by the shell (launched by fread) before the execution of `ssh`. This can be confirmed through

```
data.table::fread(cmd='ssh user@remote awk -vsh=123 \\"{print $0 FILENAME}\\" path/to/myfile.txt')
```

which gives you a table of `"123path/to/myfile.txt"`.

To pass the correct script command to `awk`, you have to do a lot of escaping, several possible solutions are:

```
data.table::fread(cmd="ssh user@remote awk {print\\\\ \\\\\\$0\\\\,FILENAME} path/to/myfile*.txt")
# that's a lot of "\"'s.

data.table::fread(cmd="ssh user@remote awk '{print\\ \\$0\\,FILENAME} path/to/myfile*.txt")
# A lot of characters still requires escaping, including ` `, `,`, `$` and `"`

data.table::fread(cmd=r"(ssh user@remote awk \''{print $0,FILENAME}'\' path/to/myfile*.txt)")
# now you can write awk scripts almost natively.
```

To make such escaping, first, you have your command to be executed in the remote server, for example,

```
awk '{print $0"\t"FILENAME}' path/to/myfile*.txt
# or without `'`
awk {print\ \$0\"\\t\"FILENAME} path/to/myfile*.txt
# if you use `,` in the script, either `{`, `}` or `,` should be escaped 
awk \{print\ \$0,FILENAME} path/to/myfile*.txt
```

- `awk` takes the script argument as one argument, so  's should be escaped if not quoted.
- `$0` will be substituted unless it is quoted by `'`, or its `$` is escaped.
- A `\` will leave the character after it "as is", unless it is quoted by `'`.
- `{A,B}` will be expanded ([brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)) unless any one of `{`, `,` or `}` is escaped.

then you should escape the command in your local shell:

```
# keep the statement using `''` quotation
ssh user@remote awk \''{print $0"\t"FILENAME}'\' path/to/myfile*.txt # the `'` can be escape using `\`
ssh user@remote awk '{print\ \$0\"\\t\"FILENAME}' path/to/myfile*.txt
ssh user@remote awk '\{print\ \$0,FILENAME}' path/to/myfile*.txt

# otherwise, escape anything that can break an argument or be substituted by the local shell
ssh user@remote awk \'{print\ \$0\"\\t\"FILENAME}\' path/to/myfile*.txt
ssh user@remote awk {print\\ \\\$0\\\"\\\\t\\\"FILENAME} path/to/myfile*.txt
ssh user@remote awk \\\{print\\\ \\\$0,FILENAME} path/to/myfile*.txt
```

And finally you escape all `\` and quotation marks in the R string:

```
cmd=r"(ssh user@remote awk \''{print $0"\t"FILENAME}'\' path/to/myfile*.txt)"

# really A LOT of `\`'s
cmd='ssh user@remote awk {print\\\\ \\\\\\$0\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\t\\\\\\"FILENAME} path/to/myfile*.txt'
```

Now you can enjoy reading files from the remote server without creating any intermediate files!